# How can I make use of Visual Studio's regular expression to replace multiple lines of code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, regex, replace

Is it possible to make use of Visual Studio 2005/2008 "Find" and "Replace" functionality along with regular expression to replace multiple lines of already coded C# code into a single line of code?

Note that Visual Studio's "Find" and "Replace" regular expression syntax differs from .NET Framework.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
.|\n
```

The "." matches any character, the "\n" matches a newline character, and the "|" tells you to match either the "." or the "\n."

Comment: Wouldn't that just delete everything?

Comment: I was responding to his "How do I perform "Matches any single character including line breaks" question.

Answer (score 1):

\n is the newline character in the Find & Replace syntax.  Just replace \n with nothing.

Comment: How do I perform "Matches any single character including line breaks".

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

In the find & replace dialog:
Get everything between "START" and "END"

START(.|\n)*?END